# Get your own account's followers info on Instagram

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm looking for an API for getting my own followers information (mostly Instagram ID).
I checked the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) documentation but the best thing I found is the number of my followers but not the actual data about them.

Getting your own followers public info seems like a reasonable thing to ask from Facebook's API, assuming I can do it manually using the app. However, seems like the new API doesn't have support for that (?).

Comment: why would it be a reasonable thing? what would you do with the account followers?

Comment: An even more reasonable thing to expect is _privacy_. Just because I follow you and look at your pictures, doesn’t mean you have the right to know details about me / my profile.

Comment: Hey guys, reasonable in a sense of public information only. The same information I can see manually by going to my followers page on my Instagram app.

Comment: that is no excuse for (automated) data collection. so what is the use case for it? what would you do with the account info of your followers?

Comment: @luschn cmon that's a little extra, there are many instances where automated data collection are certainly excusable. And lets keep in mind its PUBLIC data.

Comment: @04FS then I recommend you make your profile private

Comment: data being plubic does not mean you are allowed to use/grab it.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated a long time ago as facebook does not want you to access other peoples data. Not sure if you've heard about the past/recent issues going on but checkout Mashable or something